# using pellet OWL reasoner on a cluster

Tags: owl, semantic-web, pellet

I recently gained access to computing cluster (using a Linux OS). Has anyone had any experience running pellet (https://github.com/stardog-union/pellet) on a cluster? I have some large ABox datasets I would like to run using pellet.

Comment: Pellet is an open-source OWL reasoner, there is no cluster support. Distributed OWL reasoning is research topic, progress is stuck in the last decade as it's far away from being trivial. In addition, Pellet is not maintained anymore, expertise is nowadays contained inside the Stardog triple store, which in fact supports to setup the triple store on a cluster.

Comment: Indeed, you can run Pellet on a single machine and increase the Java heap space. Anything beyond isn't supported.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how much heap space I'm allowed to use on the cluster ... I'll have to experiment :)

Comment: https://github.com/Galigator/openllet is very simmilar to Pellet. But a cluster mode would be a little tricky as reasoning have a bad complexity. A better approch is to cluster data more that cluster reasoning.

Comment: @Galigator Thanks for the link to openllet. Not sure I understand your comment about clustering data, though.